# Comma and assignment operators in C

Tags: c, c99, comma-operator

I have the following:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
a = b, c = d;
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", a, b, c, d);
```

The output is:

```
2, 2, 4, 4
```

How does the comma operator work with assignment operators? From what I have known it would evaluate and return the second expression if we have,

```
(exp1, exp2)
```

So, why would it evaluate `a = b` ?

Answer (score 5):

The first operand is evaluated and the result discarded. The second operand is then evaluated, and the result returned as the overall result of the expression.

The standard says:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
>   has its type and value.

Comment: Additionally, the assignment operator has a side effect: It stores the value of the right side, converted to the type of the left, in the object referred to by the left side. So evaluating an assignment causes the assignment to be made, even if the value produced by the assignment is not otherwise used.

Answer (score 4):

The comma operator is lower precedence than assignment. All expressions in a comma operator are evaluated, but only the last is used as the resulting value. So both assignments are performed. The result of the comma operator in your case would be the result of `c = d`. This result is not used.

Comment: Can you show that how can the result be used? I have tried something like this: `x = a = b, c = d;` So `x` must be `4` right?

Comment: `int e = (a=b, c=d);`, for example.

Comment: `x` would be 2 in your case, because assignment is still higher precedence than the comma operator. You need parentheses, as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator evaluates both its operands (the left one first) and returns the value of the right one. This is not specific to the operands being assignments.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as if you would write them as single statements:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;

a = b;
c = d;
```

For further details see also [Comma Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

From wikipedia:

```
int a=1, b=2, c=3, i;   // comma acts as separator in this line, not as an operator
i = (a, b);             // stores b into i                                                              ... a=1, b=2, c=3, i=2
i = a, b;               // stores a into i. Equivalent to (i = a), b;                                   ... a=1, b=2, c=3, i=1
i = (a += 2, a + b);    // increases a by 2, then stores a+b = 3+2 into i                               ... a=3, b=2, c=3, i=5
i = a += 2, a + b;      // increases a by 2, then stores a into i. Equivalent to  (i = a += 2), a + b;  ... a=3, b=2, c=3, i=3
i = a, b, c;            // stores a into i                                                              ... a=5, b=2, c=3, i=5
i = (a, b, c);          // stores c into i
```

Answer (score 0):

`From what I have known it would evaluate and return the second expression`

That's not a completely correct statement. Yes, the second is evaluated and returned, but you're implying the first is ignored.

The way the comma operator works is all expressions are evaluated and the **last** is returned. For example:

```
int a, b, c, d = 0;
if(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d == 1)
    printf("No it isn't!\n")
else
    printf("a: %d, b: %d, c: %d, d: %d\n", a, b, c, d);
```

Gives you:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 0
```

Because all of the expressions were evaluated, but only `d==1` was returned to make the decision for the conditional.

...a better use for this operator might be in a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; counter--, i++) // we can keep track of two different counters
                                      // this way going in different directions.
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent to this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
a = b;
c = d;
```

First expression to the left of comma gets evaluated, then the one to its right. The result of the right most expression is stored in the variable to the left of = sign.